# Pairing a single Bluetooth pherpheral with multiple centrals

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have created a application that will pair with a BLE in a door. That will open/close the door. If a user moves and opened the door using BLE from his phone. If any other user came nearby the door and tried to pair the device with door BLE, then i need to pair two devices at same time with Door BLE. is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's possible but I think that multiple concurrent connections is clearly designed to be performed by a Central instead of a Peripheral. Read BLE Core Spec 4.2, Vol 1, Part A, 6.2 Generic Access Profile :

> The **Peripheral** role is optimized for devices that support a single connection
>   and are less complex than central devices. Devices supporting the peripheral
>   role only require Controllers that support the Controller’s slave role. The
>   **Central** role supports multiple connections and is the initiator for all
>   connections with devices in the peripheral role.

In the Vol 6, Part B, 1.1.1, we also find this :

> The Link Layer in the Connection State operating in the Slave Role may
>   have multiple connections.

There may be a device that can handle multiple Central connections at the same time, but since it's less common than the other case it will be difficult to find, to develop and to maintain.

Concerning your design I'm not sure to understand what you want to perform, but here's a usecase that is totally possible and standard :

1. User 1 connects his phone with the door, pairing and bonding happen
2. User 2 connects his phone with the door, pairing and bonding happen
3. Some time passes, the door is closed and is advertising.
4. User 1 arrives near the door, his phone detects the advertising and reconnects using its bonding data, the door opens itself
5. The door is now closed again and restarted advertising
6. User 2 arrives near the door, his phone detects the advertising and reconnects using its bonding data, the door opens itself.
7. Repeat

So we have a 2-state door : When closed the door is advertising, and when connected it's open (or opening). It can handle only one connection at a time which is not a problem since if User 1 opens the door, User 2 doesn't have to open it too (it's already open). It can memorize multiple devices so both User 1 and User 2 will be able to reconnect with the door (as long as your BLE device has enough memory to store multiple bonding information).

Opening the door could be possible by writing in a characteristic that is at least in Mode 1 Level 3. Closing the door would be triggered by the disconnection, a timeout or some PIR sensor. A difficulty would be to restrict the pairing/bonding to the known users and not to allow it to any users. Here you have to find a way to differentiate trusted devices from other devices, but once bonding is done only bonded devices will be able to access this characteristic.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Will the advertising data can read by many (bonded/nonbonded) devices at same time?

Comment: Yes, that's why we call it as advertising.

Comment: It's not nonstandard anymore since Bluetooth 4.1 for a peripheral to support multiple central connections.

Comment: @Emil I have read that too but none of the BLE stacks I use implement this feature. Do you have any example ?

Comment: @Emil Thanks, I've edited my answer to remove the `non-standard` term. However I still think it's not the best approach for this usecase.